# PDF on S3 Served As image/png

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3, mime-types, content-type

I've uploaded some PDF files to S3 and some of them, but not all of them, have the following issue:

S3 reports the Content-Type as 'application/pdf', but it actually serves them as 'image/png', which of course breaks code meant to display PDF files.

Below are screenshots first of the file metadata on S3, and then of what network tools says of the same file.

[image: S3]

[image: Network Tools]

Comment: A curl of that object shows the correct content-type. Have you made any changes to this file? If not it's possible the request you captured is being modified by a proxy or by a plugin in the browser you are using. curl -I https://s3.amazonaws.com/uat-file-attachments/versions/images/000/000/088/original/Cuban_Garlic_Chicken_Recipe_-_Food.pdf
 Returned: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/pdf

Comment: It was a configuration issue somewhere in my code, though I can't recall where at this point.  It is, however, fixed now.